# Microsoft Access query - not returning all data

Tags: sql, ms-access

Suppose I have the following tables:

- Table1: FLP, FNAME, LNAME
- Table2: FLP, Job, Company, Location
- Table3: FLP, Status, Salary, Position

All are linked together by the FLP.

When I am trying to query to get all fields in all tables suppose my query is the following

```
Select *
From Table1, Table2, Table3
Where Table1.FLP = Table2.FLP AND Table1.FLP = Table3.FLP
```

However, suppose that one of the tables does not contain information or the record thus doesn't have an FLP.

For example: If i inserted into table1 `johndoe1, john, doe`,
and into table2 `johndoe1, developer, comp, usa`,
but did not insert anything into table 3 since the information is optional

my query will not fetch the result since it will fail at `Table1.FLP= Table3.FLP`

Sometimes `table2` does not contain any information

If i tried my query as follows

```
Select *
From Table1, Table2, Table3
Where Table1.FLP = Table2.FLP OR Table1.FLP = Table3.FLP
```

then it will fetch all the results but mixes them up for example johndoe1 will have information from table3 that isn't equal to johndoe1 thus creating multiple results with different values.

If needed more explanation or the real table design please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use LEFT JOIN:

```
Select * From Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.FLP = Table2.FLP LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.FLP = Table3.FLP;
```

This will give you a null entry whenever there is no matching element in a right hand table.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for your help, i was trying to working with left outer join before you gave me this answer, however your answer ss giving me a syntax error missing operator in a query expression. i think its the case of having multiple joins in the same statement

Comment: ok i managed to fix it, it has something to do with Microsoft Access it should be as follows

    Select * From ((Table1) LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.FLP = Table2.FLP) LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.FLP = Table3.FLP; 

Thanks to @ShoeDah7